# How can I TOGGLE..?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm expecting that when clicking the chevron icon it will display the languages with their formatting and expand the container, and clicking the cross icon will close the container.

```js
const toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.lang-toggle')

toggles.forEach(toggle => {
  toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    toggle.parentNode.classList.toggle('active')
  })
})
```

```css
.lang-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.lang-toggle:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.lang-toggle .fa-times {
  display: none;
}

.lang.active .lang-toggle .fa-times {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}

.lang.active .lang-toggle .fa-chevron-down {
  display: none;
}

.lang.active .lang-toggle {
  background-color: #9fa4a8;
}

.lang {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #9fa4a8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.language-frame-desktop {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 12px;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 6px;
}

.language-desktop {
  margin: 6px;
  height: 24px;
  justify-content: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: black;
}

.language-container {
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c8c8cb;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.language-name-box-desktop {
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  width: 122px;
  padding: 6px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #f7f7f9;
  border-radius: 12px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Language Toggle</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="lang">
    <div class="language-frame-desktop">
      <p class="language-desktop">Languages</p>
    </div>
    <div class="language-container">
      <div class="language-name-box-desktop gt hover" id="myDiv">
        <img src="./icons/JS.svg" alt="more" class="language-icon" id="demo">
        <p class="language-name">JavaScript</p>
      </div>
      <div class="language-name-box-desktop gt hover">
        <img src="./icons/HTML.svg" alt="more" class="language-icon">
        <p class="language-name">HTML</p>
      </div>
      <div class="language-name-box-desktop gt hover">
        <img src="./icons/CSS.svg" alt="more" class="language-icon">
        <p class="language-name">CSS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="lang-toggle">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </button>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

So basically what you are doing wrong is you are not updating the `display : none` to `display :block` for the `.language-container`
so to fix that you can do these changes in your JS and CSS files.

```
.language-container {
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #c8c8cb;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.toggled{
  display: none;
}
```

and for your JS

```
const toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.lang-toggle')
const toggled=document.querySelector(".language-container")

toggles.forEach(toggle => {
    toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        toggle.parentNode.classList.toggle('active')
        toggled.classList.toggle('toggled')
    
    })
})
```

And this will work fine.